# Can compound variables be used as function arguments in ksh?

Tags: shell, oop, ksh

How do you use compound variables in non-trivial situations like function parameters in ksh? Is it possible? How would you make the commented lines in this example code work?

```
func(){
    print ${1.a}  #reference argument object members. output would be 'dog'
    newObject=$1  #assign compound variable to new variable
    echo ${newObject.a} ${newObject.b}  #output would be 'dog cat'
}
obj=( a=dog b=cat )
func $obj  #call function with compound argument
```

Clarification: This is not an associative array in bash. It is a compound variable (like an object) in ksh.

Comment: what are you expecting as output/results? also, try running your code with `set -x` enabled ... does the `obj` array contain what you think it does? are you passing to `func` what you think you're passing?

Comment: I expect it to break because the syntax is wrong and I don't know how to fix it. obj is not an array, it's more like a struct with members `${obj.a}` and `${obj.b}`. When used as a function parameter, $1 get assigned to the text `(` instead of to an object like I want.

Comment: yeah, we know it's going to break; the question relates to what you're expecting as output/results **if** you can get it to work

Comment: I want the object passed as a parameter to be accessible inside the function. the 'echo' line and the comment on the 'print' line show what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to dust off the `ksh` cobwebs ...

There are a couple steps:

- pass the variable name (not the value) to the function
- in the function use `typeset -n` (or `nameref`) to allow the function to reference the array by a 'local' name

One example would look like:

```
$ func(){
    typeset -n newObject=${1}
    echo ".${newObject.a}.${newObject.b}."
}

$ obj=( a=dog b=cat )
$ func obj
.dog.cat
```

Here's a [ksh fiddle](http://tpcg.io/pSFqPTmU)